# converting python list [1.] to [(1,)]

Tags: python, list, data-conversion

I have the following lists in python:

```
a=[(0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,) (0,)] 

b=[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
```

and I would like to convert `b` into the same format as `a`, but I can't figure out how to do this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not what lists look like in Python. Are you actually using NumPy arrays? Why do you think you need the first format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
b2 = [(x,) for x in b]
```

Comment: Just a typo I think, but don't you mean `b2 = [(x,) for x in b]`?

Comment: @dawg yes, thanks. Other answer made the same mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

You want tuples of size 1, containing integers:

```
b = [(int(number),) for number in b]
```